# Dropdown menus align

Tags: html, css

Under each "Something" there should be two submenus next to each other.

My HTML so far.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
  <head>
   <style>
    #whatever div {
     float:left;

     width: 100%;
    }

    #test {
     width:30%;
     display:inline-block;
    }


    .dropdown {
     position:relative;
     display: inline-block;

    }

    .dropdown-content {
     display: none;
     position: relative;

     min-width: 160px;
     box-shadow: 0px 8px 16px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    }

    .dropdown-content a {
     color: black;
     padding: 12px 16px;
     text-decoration: none;
     display: block;
    }

    .dropdown-content a:hover {background-color: #f1f1f1}

    .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
     display: block;
    }

    .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
     background-color: #3e8e41;
    }
   </style>
   <div id="whatever">
    <span id="test">Something</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
     <button class="dropbtn">ULL</button>
     <div class="dropdown-content">
      <a href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a href="#">Link 3</a>
     </div>
    </div>

    <span id="test">Something</span>
    <span id="test">Something</span>
</div>
  </body>
 </html>
```

So basically, as you can see, I need to add another submenu next ULL and I need to do the same under Something title.

Comment: Making it valid HTML might help ;-) Right now you're missing a closing `</div>` for `<div id="whatever">`.

Comment: Tnx...done that now, but still my problem is not solved :)

Comment: You should edit the question with the updated code.

Answer (score 0):

(Last Edition)
Notes:

- write 0 instead of 0px
- open body tag after closed head tag
- close div tag
- set position for other ull buttons

Here is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        #whatever div {
            float: left;
            width: 100%;
        }

        .test {
            width: 30%;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .dropdown-content {
            display: none;
            position: absolute;
            min-width: 160px;
            box-shadow: 0 8px 16px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
        }

        .dropdown-content a {
            color: black;
            padding: 12px 16px;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown-content a:hover {
            background-color: #f1f1f1
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropdown-content {
            display: block;
        }

        .dropdown:hover .dropbtn {
            background-color: #3e8e41;
        }
    </style>
<body>
<div id="whatever">
    <span class="test">Something</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn">ULL</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="position: absolute;top: 26px;left: 50px;">ULL</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>

    </div>
    <span class="test">Something</span>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="position: absolute;top: 26px;left: 410px;">ULL</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="dropbtn" style="position: absolute;top: 26px;left: 450px;">ULL</button>
        <div class="dropdown-content">
            <a href="#">Link 1</a>
            <a href="#">Link 2</a>
            <a href="#">Link 3</a>
        </div>
        </div>
        <span class="test">Something</span>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" style="position: absolute;top: 26px;left: 820px;">ULL</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="dropdown">
            <button class="dropbtn" style="position: absolute;top: 26px;left: 860px;">ULL</button>
            <div class="dropdown-content">
                <a href="#">Link 1</a>
                <a href="#">Link 2</a>
                <a href="#">Link 3</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Ok, this is closer to solution now Mahdyar Irani, but as i Stated befoe, i need 2 ULL submenus nex to each other under every Something title.

Comment: It's close :)...you dont have submenus in middle title and menus all open on left side...it still need some work, but I appreciated the effort :).

Comment: You mean all of dropdown-content's text align be center?

Comment: So add 'text-align: center;' to dropdown-content class

Comment: @CSSNoob Please choose best answer